# Is there a way to keep track of who is accessing azure vms?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, user-input, azure-monitoring

I'm setting a server as a windows virtual desktop host pool. Is there a way to keep track of who is accessing the server?

Now I am using Azure Log Analytics workspaces to connect with VM, I've tried to find some queries to get the information of who is accessing the server.

```
Query:

VMConnection
|where computer == 'TestVM01'
```

I except the output of who is accessing the server, but I don't know how to write the query.  If you know some information about it, please share your idea here, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the VM, or logging on to the VM?

Logging on to the VM would be OS logging, eg Windows Event Audit Logs or whatever the Linux logs are.
Accessing the VM would be network traffic, or in other words: Your NSG flow logs for which you would need to have Network Watcher configured. You would be able to see which source tries to access at which point in time on which port (RDP/SSH)

So you could relate both of those logs with each other by matching the time-stamps.
AFAIK the portal and thus the logs from Azure itself, don't keep track of which person tries to access a VM for logon.
I believe it is possible to have Windows Event Logs sent to Log Analytics, or actually, have Log analytics fetch the Event logs, no clue for Linux logs. So that's one part of the whole, I do not know if you can do the same for the NSG flow logs.